# Explaining the following statement in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I would like you guys to help me out with the following things in this program. I am a beginner in java so would appreciate any help on this:

What does this means?

```
   private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton
```

Are we creating a variable with type as class. I have seen many places this practice. Can you tell me why we create variables/objects with Class name?

This "Singleton singleton " is this a variable declaration or object declaration.

2)Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance()

Can someone help what are we doing here?  We have created another object "tmp" right? What's the statement at right side doing?

```
public class Singleton {

   private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

   /* A private Constructor prevents any other 
    * class from instantiating.
    */
   private Singleton() {}

   /* Static 'instance' method */
   public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return singleton;
   }

   /* Other methods protected by singleton-ness */
   protected static void demoMethod() {
      System.out.println("demoMethod for singleton"); 
   }
}
```

File: SingletonDemo.java

```
public class SingletonDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance( );
  tmp.demoMethod( );
}
```

Comment: Google singleton pattern, it suppose to return always the same instance of an object.

Comment: I don't need help as of now with this Singleton thing, but just want to know why and when we use things like Classname classname. And is classname here a reference to object or variable. It would be great if someone can help me in brushing this concept of mine

Comment: Java is case insensitive, so the names `Classname` and `classname` refer to two different things; from the computer's perspective, these are no less the same than the words "ice cream" and "tornado". There's no particular reason why they are the same English word. Typically, class names will start with an upper-case letter and variable names with a lower-case letter, so that's the easiest way to tell the difference.

Comment: Telling you to google something *is* an attempt to help you.  Why would you ask someone to spend hours restating something that has been stated millions of times?

Comment: Sorry guys if i missed something. i am not asking about Singleton.It's just that what i have mentioned in the answer. Just an explanation of this thing:private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton

Singleton singleton

what's this an object declaration or class variable?

If variable why are we using new keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question asks what this means:

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

This could have equally been written as:

```
private static Singleton myVariable = new Singleton();
```

When you see `Class class` it's a variable declaration. The first word is the type of the variable, and the second is the name of the variable.  The type (or class name) is defined by whoever wrote the class.  The variable name is up to you.  It's just common to use the class name all in lowercase for the variable name.

For the second question, you ask about

```
Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance();
```

Here we have a variable called **tmp** of type **Singleton** that is initialized to the result of a function call.  The function call is `Singleton.getInstance()`. That is a `static` method which means you don't need an instance of the class to call it.  It just returns the object so that you can access it.

Note that in the first case it initializes the `private` variable using `new Singleton()`.  The use of `new` causes an object creation.  In the second case there is no object creation.  It's asking the `Singleton` class to give it something that was already created.

Comment: Okay so now i am confused. You said The use of new causes an object creation.  Now when we wrote Classname classname = new Classname(); then classname is a variable of Classname type, right? So when we used the new keyword than it became an object? How come a variable is changed to an object? Are variables and objects the same thing?

Comment: The part that does the creation is `new Classname()`.  That tells `Java` to create a new `Classname` object.  The result (the new object) is then stored in your variable because the equal-sign tells it to set that object as the variable's value.  The variable is not changed to an object. A variable is just a pointer to something, and what happens here is that the variable is told to point to the new object.

Comment: Oh ok awesome. So that means the value of this variable is actually that object and that object stores something. But i have learnt that when we create an object like Test t= new Test(); then T is reference variable to the object pointing to the location of the object and not storing the value of the object? Can you please explain this as well. Thanks for the answers so far

Comment: i am waiting for your answer, you have cleared most of my doubt

Comment: When an object is created it lives in memory and is pointed to by a variable. If no variables point to it any more, then the object can be deleted since nobody can use it. If you have a variable `t` that references an object, then you can do something with that object.  A variable is kind of like a telephone number that lets you get at an object (the phone it will ring to).  The telephone number is not the phone, it's a reference to it.

Comment: Awesome i was reading this documentation, can you explain this as well in simple terms to me: Instance variables (non-static fields) are unique to each instance of a class. Class variables (static fields) are fields declared with the static modifier; there is exactly one copy of a class variable, regardless of how many times the class has been instantiated

Comment: When you write a class it usually will have some variables it keeps internally that the outside world doesn't need to know about. Ones that are `static` are called class variables because they can be accessed directly from the class without creating an object first. Non-static ones are called instance variables because you need an instance of the class (ie, an object created with `new`) before they can be referenced. That's because the memory where those variables are stored is different.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name is simply a name. It has no requirement to be anything.  Please read [this documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)  Convention is to have it in camel-case, lower-case first letter. But it can be anything. It makes no difference in terms of function whether or not it is named the same as the class name or other.

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

Is not different than

```
private static Singleton Singleton = new Singleton(); // Bad style
private static Singleton s = new Singleton();
private static Singleton xyz = new Singleton();
```

All are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Okay. So i have seen many programmers use the way of Singleton singleton and not the other way around. Is there some logic/ need behind that? Also the same questions that i asked in comment to svcisco"You said The use of new causes an object creation. Now when we wrote Classname classname = new Classname(); then classname is a variable of Classname type, right? So when we used the new keyword than it became an object? How come a variable is changed to an object? Are variables and objects the same thing? "

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance()
```

it is not an another object. it is another reference, by `getInstance()`. that is singleton design

**Singleton**
 single or same object maintain for a class through out the runtime of VM.
[refer here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Sorry i confused it with singleton. what about this   private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton

Comment: single or same object maintain for a class through out the runtime of VM

Comment: Suppose my class in Company and i write it like this: Company company; what does this mean then? Is company a variable or an object

Comment: *company* is a variable or reference. object is *new Company()*. 
for example : Company abc = new Company(). here abc is a reference to object. then Company xyz = abc. here xyz is another reference for the same object.

Answer (score 0):

As for the variable vs object question, an object is essentially a collection of meaningful values somewhere in memory, comprised of a list of methods and feilds, among other things. Every 'live' object has a reference variable that points to it (tells you where in memory it is), which is a variable with its type = the class of the object. In your code, the variable 'singleton' points to an object of the 'Singleton' class, which was created by the constructor method `new Singleton()`, the method `getInstance()` returns the location in memory of that Singleton object, so you can place it in a new variable. tmp is an example of this happening, its another variable that holds the reference to the same Singleton object.